# Unable to upload file size more than 160 KB using ASP Runner 6.2

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have developed one small application using ASP RUNNER 6.2.
Everything seems to be fine with this application, but I cant able to import or upload file size more than 160 KB. Here I'm uploading xls format sheet. 
Even I have changed AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed value to 3000000 (default is 200 KB) in METABASE.XML file in C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv path of my server.

Server details are as follows - IIS V 6

Microsoft Windows Server 2003
Standard Edition
Service Pack 2

When I'm uploading more file size, I'm getting the below error.

> Import didn’t succeed, couldn’t find following fields: F37, F38, F39, F40, F41, F42, F43, F44, F45, F46, F47, F48, F49, F50, F51, F52

Please suggest me to solve this as soon as possible, I have completed every thing and got struck up with this work.

Comment: Perhaps download the [IIS Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17275) and check your updating `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` in the correct place by using the MetaBase Explorer application? Haven't had any dealings with ASP Runner so can't really comment on specific errors related to that application.